# Changing SASS With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Is it possible for javascript to change SASS properties 
 I have already tried using javascript to manipulate the DOM, but it still doesn't work

Example:

HTML:

```
<div id="thing1"></div>
```

SASS

```
#thing1
    display: none
    width: 40vw
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: red
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("thing1").style.display = "block"
```

Can someone show me how to make this work

Comment: Why not use JS to change classes instead?

Comment: That could work, but I don't know how to do that, could you explain how to change classes using JS

Comment: [How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/195951)

Comment: You won't be able to modify SASS with JavaScript as the browser only sees the generated CSS.

Comment: You can change CSS variable values via JavaScript, but not SASS properties